# Quad Remesher edges

Tags: edges, remesh

I used Quad Remesher on stylized hair, and the all the pointy edges of the hair are destroyed.

Is there anyway to avoid it? I tired using the X4 Vertex map but it doest help.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello, was your mesh made of quads before the remesh? In that case what does it give if you use Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide instead?

Comment: I used Remesh add-on before it..

Comment: what does it give if you use Ctrl E > Un-Subdivide instead of Quad Remesh?